# my juvenile bearded dragon still dull and greyish after shedding tail

Tags: reptiles, breeding, adoption

My juvenile bearded dragon sheds every few weeks. We haven't had any problems so far. I mist several times a day and his eating habits haven't changed. With that being said he is shedding his tail which always goes first and it is still dull and grey underneath. Is this something I should worry about or could he be shedding another layer sooner than normal?

Answer (score 2):

I personally wouldn't worry about it too much. Just continue to mist daily, with the occasional shallow bath (mine love them!). If their feeding/dietary habits haven't amended, that's a positive.

I would get concerned when they are having issues actually shedding, whereby the skin does not come off. Although, this can be assisted, albeit with care, by soaking the area and gently rolling off the hanging skin (I would not recommend this if you're not comfortable, as this **could** harm the reptile).